# How to show real time traffic data for a particular route on maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have implemented direction API to find out a route from source to destination using Google Maps V3 direction API in browser/JavaScript.

Now I want to display traffic situation as shown in below snapshot (snapshot from google maps) in the route part only.

[image]

Is there a way to do so with different polyline strokeColor for different level of traffic condition?

If it is not possible using direction API or traffic layer, can I make use of the premium version of direction matrix or road API to implement this?

Below is what I have done until now and my output accordingly:

```
  var map;
  var directionsService;
  var polyline;
  var directionsDisplay;
  function initMap() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      polylineOptions:{
        strokeOpacity:1,
        strokeWeight:5,
        strokeColor: 'green'
      },
      draggable: true
    });

    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 14,
      center: {lat: 37.77, lng: -122.447}
    });

    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    trafficLayer.setMap(map);

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
               directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionsPanel'));

    directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
      DistanceOut(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
    });
    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      map:map
    });
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);

  }

  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService,    directionsDisplay) {

    directionsService.route({
      origin: 'Whitefield, Bangalore',
      destination: 'Indira nagar, Bangalore',

      provideRouteAlternatives: true,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING',
      drivingOptions: {
        departureTime: new Date(Date.now()),
        trafficModel: 'bestguess'
      },
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC

    }, function(response, status) { console.log(response);
      if (status == 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        DistanceOut(response);
        changeStepColor(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }

  function DistanceOut(response){
    document.getElementById("travelDetail").innerHTML = "Distance:"+response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text+
        "<br> Duration::"+response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text+
        "<br> Duration in traffic::"+response.routes[0].legs[0].duration_in_traffic.text;
  }

  // Here I want to change the polyline color according to the traffic condition.
  // Can I? Or if any other way to do so?!
  function changeStepColor(res){
    var steps = res.routes[0].legs[0].steps;

    for(i=0; i<steps.length; i++){
      if((steps[i].distance.value/steps[i].duration_in_traffic.value) > 5) {
        //steps[i].polyline.strokeColor='blue';
        //directionsDisplay.setOptions({polylineOptions: {path: steps[i].path ,strokeColor: 'red'}});
      } else {
        //directionsDisplay.setOptions({polylineOptions: {path: steps[i].path ,strokeColor: 'yellow'}});

        //steps[i].polyline.strokeColor='red'
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is my Output snapshot:
[image]

I hope this helps you to understand my issue. Let me know if anything else is needed to understand my issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently there is no possibility to display traffic only for a route using the Google Maps JavaScript API directions service. You can show traffic for entire city via Traffic layer, but not for single streets.

Premium plan license doesn't matter, you will have the same output for directions. Other APIs like Roads API and Distance Matrix API do not provide any traffic related information in responses.

The feature request has been filed in Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36537583

Feel free to star the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to notifications from Google.

**UPDATED**

It looks like Embed API shows traffic information for the route. Try to use Embed API in [directions mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#directions_mode). This will give you something like

[image]

Comment: in that case how come company like UBER and other are having this feature? Is that something they develop themselves?  Moreover how google is displaying traffic only for a route?

Comment: Please comment @xomena

Comment: Not sure how Uber gets this data, but there is no way to get it via Directions API or Distance Matrix API. Probably you can use the  Embed API as a workaround.

Comment: Another workaround might be analyzing the duration and duration_in_traffic fields in Directions API [response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsResponseElements). If duration_in_traffic > duration that means you have a heavier traffic than usual, otherwise you have a light traffic. After that you should plot each step as a polyline with a corresponding color.

Comment: I have tried the way you said in your second comment. But it is difficult to change polyline as duration_in_traffic mapped to legs where as there is no  duration_in_traffic data for steps polyline. Anyway can you please elaborate what and how embed api works and how did you code for the output you got above in your answer? @xomena

Comment: Great Help @xomena. This is really something I was looking for. So finally embed API is the answer for my query. I want to put lights on something else as well, Dumb people over here quarreled with me saying this is not possible. Great work.. Thanks. :)

Comment: can we also inject our own congestion feeds in specific route and application behave normally like suggesting other routes .... ?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to provide real time traffic data to a route that has been built. First off , in order to do this, you will need a Google Maps Premium Plan client ID. In order to display traffic information to a route, you will need to implement a [Directions Request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests). Previous you could use a `durationInTraffic` but that has since been deprecated. You must now use the [`drivingOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DrivingOptions) which can then be applied to your custom polyline.

Comment: As I see for direction api, there is no difference in features for normal and premium plan. Are you saying to go for Road api and distanceMatrix api to get the required output? @arde

Comment: Or do you mean to say that, if i will go for premium plan, the requirement which i have will automatically fulfilled provided I am sending drivingOptions?? @arde

Comment: Yes to your second question.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Polyline from '@mapbox/polyline';

const origin = `${currentPosition.latitude}, ${currentPosition.longitude}`; 
const destination = `${User.latitude}, ${User.longitude}`; 

try {
    const waypoints = this.outletCoordinates.map(waypoint => 
      `${waypoint.latitude},${waypoint.longitude}`).join('|');
    const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${origin}&destination=${destination}&waypoints=optimize:true|${waypoints}&key=${Config.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}&mode=DRIVING`;

    const mapUrl = await fetch(url); 
    const respJson = await mapUrl.json();
    const routes = _.get(respJson, 'routes', []);
    if (routes.length > 0 && routes[0]) {
        const routeDescrip = routes[0]; 
        const [summaryLeg] = routeDescrip.legs || []; 
        const points = Polyline.decode(routeDescrip.overview_polyline.points); 
        const optimizedRoutes = points.map(point => ({
          latitude: point[0],
          longitude: point[1],
        }));
    }
}
```